# inverse ring index to get the greatest index as the first of the first index on C

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm not sure about how to get an inverse index , index%size it's ok to a straight ring index but what I need  it's if tou are in 0 index get the last index as the previous of 0.

```
[0][1][2][3] // the previous index of 0 should be 3
```

Comment: Which language? NB: this hardly classifies as an algorithm question. It is more relevant to tag the programming language.

Comment: The language is c

Comment: OK then you need `(index+n-1)%n`. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the language *C* the remainder operator can be used as follows to get a true (positive) modulo result:

```
(index+n-1)%n
```

where *n* is the length of your array.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, then you could just say `prev(index) = (index-1) % len(array)` given that `%` returns the modulus and not the remainder (depending on the language, the `mod` operation might have slightly different behavior with **negative** integers)

```
int m(int a,int b){
return (a % b + b) % b;
}
```

so you would just define `prev(n) = m(n-1,len(array))`

Comment: In c I get  -1 not a 3